# Using Tree Tab Structure

Tags: website-design, user-behavior, interface, accessibility, tabs

I have a situation where i have a tab structure and there are other options under each main tab so i have picked up tree tab structure where i show primary tab and secondary tab visually different.

as par old design when user scrolls down top level main tab gets converted into drop down and i think this is confusing.
and
as par new design i have made two tabs look visually different but when scrolled down sticking two tabs will not look is what i feel.
is there any other solution where i can show the context of tab when user is scrolling down

[image: Old Design two tabs]

[image: old design after scroll it changes to drop down]

[image: primary tabs converted into drop down]

[image: new design]

Comment: could you elaborate what you need properly? \

Comment: simple....I have two tabs one above another one and when user scrolls down i don't want user to lose about context like in which tab is user currently viewing data ,so according to our old design there was no differentiation between two tabs visually so in my current design i changed it so it looks visually different this is solved but when user scrolls top primary tab was changing into drop down but i do not want this in my new design so i wanted another alternative solution to hold context

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use standard dropdown navigation style as that's what it looks like you're after

[image]

Comment: not sure that this will work. because this is not the case in main page my case is in details page which comes after navigating 2 steps after home

Answer (score 1):

At first, I would highly encourage you to browse this thread [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16281/elegant-simple-and-obvious-sub-tabs), and especially the answer by **Naoise Golden**. It should be of great help in understanding what options you could explore, and why are nested tabs a tricky pattern to handle.

Having said that, I looked at your screenshots and it somehow seems like you could some more thinking with the way you are grouping content across multiple tabs. Boils down to more thoughtful Information Architecture/Taxonomy. For example, I see Portfolio as child inside the Overall category but as Parent in the form of Portfolio By Stage/Sector/Location. Just going by that and my **assumptions**, one could use intelligent filtering and better categorisation to achieve the same result. Quickly putting that into a mockup for better reference:

[image]