# Nested tabs (vertical within horizontal) alternative

Tags: web-app, information-architecture, tabs, wizard

I am working on a component is part of a larger wizard. It is made up of nested tabs (only 2 levels deep). Here is a quick wireframe of the it:

[image: tabs]

The system I am working on is a refresh of an existing one. I have access to various reports and as a result of that I know that:

- There will usually be between 1 and 4 locations (98% of records have up to 4)
- Each location will usually have 2 to 3 opportunities (94% of records have up to 3 per location)

Obviously there are some outliers but they are pretty rare.

The form will be quite big so I'd rather not show multiple copies of it if I can avoid it.

Are there any alternatives that I have overlooked?

Comment: I personally don't like the separation.  My eye has to move a long ways to get location and opportunity.   Lots of options for selecting from a set list - pull down, radio button.

Comment: I don't see any reason for the variation in the design: Locations have separate title with Add function, then a tabbed list. Opportunities have only a tabbed list, with the Add function close by. Eye and mouse have to travel quite a bit... @DaveAlger's version is more consistent.

Comment: Also, some questions as to the process come to mind: This is about creation, but is it *only* about creation? Where are locations and opportunities changed? Here? You said it's "part of a larger wizard" - where does it have its controls? Are they just Previous/Next, or do you show steps as well? Also, is the inner form requiring wide space or does it look well when tall?

Comment: You may want to have a look here: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/14286/best-practices-for-tabs/14288#14288

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: nested tabs]

With only a few Locations and a few Opportunities I would probably just list two rows of links with the selected ones clearly visible.  Something like this...

Comment: This is pretty close to what I ended up going with.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the following scheme:

> Location Tabs
>
> > List of all opportunities for that location w/ search controls to display only one kind of opportunity or a combination of a few.